# How to apply .htaccess with hardcoded link or alternative for PHP to use SEO URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am coding website in PHP

And My links are :-

http://example.com/science.php?category=alien&title=Find+UFO+Just+over+your+head+by+clicking+here

Now, I want to show url in my view source as :-

http://example.com/science.php/alien/Find+UFO+Just+over+your+head+by+clicking+here

Also i want this as working link :-

From .htaccess [with the help of generateit.net > mod_rewrite generator] here is the code:-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /science.php?category=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

Now what do i need to do in PHP , to make this URL Valid.

Do i need to write below link :-

```
<a href="http://example.com/science.php?category=<?php echo $rows['category'] ?>&title=<?php echo htmlentities($rows['title']); ?>" > <?php echo $rows['title'] ?></a>
```

in my code or do i need to write :-

```
<a href="http://example.com/science.php/<?php echo $rows['category'] ?>/<?php echo htmlentities($rows['title']); ?>" > <?php echo $rows['title'] ?></a>
```

or some function to make above url.

Thank you ! I am hunting for this knowledge since long time.

Thanks once again

Comment: I want to show http://example.com/science.php/alien/Find+UFO+Just+over+your+head+by+clicking+here this link to visitor, and not direct link like this => http://example.com/science.php?category=alien&title=Find+UFO+Just+over+your+head+by+clicking+here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is no need for any change from PHP Side, because php will receive request after translated by .httaccess file.

Now i think there is something wrong with your .httaccess conditions, please try below code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /$1.php?category=$2&title=$3 [L]
```

and after save, try link below

```
http://example.com/science/alien/Find+UFO+Just+over+your+head+by+clicking+here
```

I hope this help

Comment: so do you mean, i can write my link like this in php ?
<a href="http://example.com/index.php?category=<?php echo $rows['category'] ?>&title=<?php echo htmlentities($rows['title']); ?>" > <?php echo $rows['title'] ?></a>

Comment: ^^ will that auto-render my all links of webpage..

or do i need to write it like
`<a href="http://example.com/index.php/<?php echo $rows['category']; ?>/<?php echo htmlentities($rows['title']); ?>" > <?php echo $rows['title'] ?></a>`

Comment: Go for the second approach ;-) That's waht you wanted, didn't you?

Comment: Yes the second one is correct, but you have to remove (.php) ext. for example: http://example.com/index/<?php echo $rows['category']; ?>.. etc